# While pasting data from SSMS in Grid view (SQL Server Management Studio) to Excel, all the column data is in one single column

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I queried select statement in SQL Server in grid view, and tried pasting the data into Excel. There were many columns, but when pasting into Excel, the data shows up in a single column. Can't understand why

Comment: Are you pasting from a Grid Virew or Text View? I have never had a problem copying from Grid View to Excel.

Comment: @Larnu I pasted it from Grid View. I too never faced this problem before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in SSMS the output of the query is displayed in Grid View. Copy from grid view to excel. I actually use this very often, it always works.

Comment: I copies it from Grid View only. I have previously done the same thing and it worked but this problem occurred for the first time. I doubt any excel setting has been changed.

Comment: @AmitGoel : Just to make sure on the steps : So you run the query in SSMS with option Results to Grid, you then go the the grid in SSMS, select all, then right click -> copy with headers, open new Excel book, click on a cell in the Excel book, paste into Excel. Does this process result in all columns from SSMS ending up in 1 column in Excel?

Comment: @AmitGoel : Seems really strange, because I've used this process so many times with different versions of Excel and SSMS and never had this problem. What you could do as workaround: in SSMS right click -> save results as and save to CSV, then open that CSV file in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This started to happen after I used [Data > text-to-column] in Excel with option "delimited", then unchecked "tabulation". Once I use it again, leaving "tabulation" checked, all pasting grid data resumed operating normally.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use text-to-columns in Excel after you've pasted your data in. Data > Text to columns.

Then the next time you paste it should keep the correct format.

I've also had luck with restarting both Excel and SSMS to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried doing that but after pasting sql data in excel there was no space or tab like delimeter to make the excel "Text-To-Column" work.

Comment: Is it fixed width? What happens when you paste into notepad and then into Excel?

Comment: While pasting data in notepad the columns are separated with tabs but while pasting in excel its coming in single excel column. I think any excel setting has changed mistakenly.

Comment: And if you paste from notepad into Excel?

Comment: Pasting the data from notepad to excel, then also data is coming in one column. I think there is some settings problem in excel.